# XML encoding declaration and endianness

Tags: java, xml, parsing, character-encoding

I'm tidying up some of my really old Java code, written to the first edition of the XML spec before XML parsing was included in the JDK libraries, and trying to bring it up to date as well as write some tests. In particular I'm (re)implementing XML [character encoding autodetection](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-guessing-no-ext-info) like this:

1. I read the BOM, if any.
2. If there is no BOM, I "impute" a BOM based upon the expected `<?xml` start of the XML declaration.
3. I now have enough information (number of bytes per character, endianness, etc.) to read my way over to the `encoding=` declaration, if any, which according to the XML spec may tell me some more specific or esoteric encoding

So let's say that the file has an actual BOM for UTF-16LE. What should be the value of the XML `encoding` attribute? Should it be `encoding="UTF-16LE"`? But the [Unicode Byte Order Mark FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM) seems to indicate that, if a UTF-16 family BOM is present, I should "tag the text" as merely `UTF-16`. Does that mean I should use `encoding="UTF-16"` in my XML file? But then should my parser ignore the `encoding` value and go with the more specific charset it has determined from the BOM? I'm starting to confuse myself.

The [W3C HTML BOM FAQ](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark.en.php) seems to indicate that tagging the text refers to "labelled in HTTP", that is, an external charset designation, presumably in the HTTP `Content-Encoding` header. So perhaps it would be OK to have an XML file starting with a BOM yet containing an XML declaration of `UTF-16LE` or `UTF-16BE`. But I have yet to see such an XML file.

If I use a UTF-16LE BOM with an XML file, 1) what value should I use in the `encoding` attribute, and 2) what charset should my parser autodetect as the encoding of the file?

Comment: For a UTF-16LE file (with or without BOM) either "UTF-16LE" or "UTF-16" would be acceptable. [Both](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml) are in the recommended [EncName](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-EncName) list.

Comment: @McDowell, thank you for providing your opinion, as well as for confirming that `UTF-16LE` and `UTF-16BE` are indeed valid names and that there exist some instances in which they may be used. I wonder if you might comment more directly to the issue I raised regarding the BOM, specifically the tension between your characterization and the Unicode Byte Order mark FAQ, and provide some reference to back up your opinions? (The reference you gave merely confirmed that these encoding names are valid in at least some instances, but made no reference to byte order marks with XML.) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The key to understanding this is to realize that the UTF-16 encoding scheme is distinct from UTF-16LE and UTF-16BE.  UTF-16, little endian, is NOT UTF-16LE.

Note especially point 4 in the last question in the Unicode BOM FAQ.  If the encoding is UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE, a BOM MUST NOT be used.  You may also refer to 3.10 in the Unicode standard for a formal definition of these "encoding schemes".

So, if you find a BOM for UTF-16, the encoding is UTF-16, NOT UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE (neither of which are allowed to have a BOM).  If there is no BOM, the encoding may be any of the three, though in that case, UTF-16 becomes basically indistinguishable from the BE and LE variants.  However, note that 4.3.3 of XML 1.1 says "Entities encoded in UTF-16 MUST and entities encoded in UTF-8 MAY begin with the Byte Order Mark".  So in the case of XML, if there is no BOM, then the encoding cannot be UTF-16 (but it may be UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).